# How to re-stream local RTSP from iOS device to the outside of local network?

Tags: ios, video-streaming, rtsp, onvif, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

I need to stream/push local IP camera's video stream to the outside of network. It could be wowza, P2P, Kinesis or just a basic server that stores/consumes the stream.

It seems like I would need a media server on iOS but I don't seem to be able to find much about it?

Does anyone know a simple way of re-streaming a local stream?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure why you need that on iOS, but I've had the same issue and went around it in two ways:

1. Mapped the port on the router for the RTSP port on the IP cam and had Wowza pull the stream, since the camera could not push it
2. Bought a different camera (Hikvision DS-2CD2455FWD-I) that was capable of RTMP push, again to a Wowza destination

Other possible solution is to have something like a PC or a Raspberry Pi reading from the RTSP and publishing to RTMP. If the camera's video codec is h264 and the audio codec is AAC, you wouldn't even have to actually re-encode the stream, just re-package it.

Comment: yeah that's what we just did actually. We mapped the port and would push it to ant media server. It worked out really well for our use case.